# How to undo sp_configure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

So I've run this code

```
use master
go

sp_configure 'show advanced options'
go

/* 0 = Disabled , 1 = Enabled */
sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO

RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

as part of a [query to rename a database](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1891/best-practice-for-renaming-a-sql-server-database/). However, I'd like to know what is the query to undo the bit of code posted. IE. put it back to its previous state.

Comment: I don't think it's actually possible. The only thing you can do is repeat the command with the previous values, but there's no "rollback" for those kind of commands.

Comment: You want to disable xp_cmdshell? It says right in the comment that 0 disables it or am I missing something?